# Why does the last line in a cell generate output but preceding lines do not?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Given this Jupyter notebook cell:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = {1,2,3,4,5}
x
y
```

When the cell executes, it generates this output:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

The last line in the cell generates output, the line above it has no effect. This works for any data type, as far as I can tell.

Here's a snip of the same code as above:

[image: Same code as above!]

Comment: The last element in a cell will be the cell output.

Comment: @Ryno_XLI Well, yes, but why and how can that be changed? Is there a config setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change this behaviour with:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

The reason why only the last line is printed is that the default value of `ast_node_interactivity` is: **`last_expr`**.

You can read more about that here:
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add explicit `print()` calls. So for example you can do

```
print(x)
print(y)
```

to print out both values.

Comment: That kind-of works but it eliminates the output formatting for data structures such as DataFrames and Series.

Comment: With the default setting where only the last line of the notebook cell is special, you can use `display(df)` inside a cell when something like a Pandas dataframe or series isn't being invoked on the last line of a cell. (You'll probably need to issue `from IPython.display import display` somewhere earlier in your notebook.) For understanding why the last line is the only one special in notebook by default it may be help to know that IPython evolved from the normal Python console and so often you could just type the variable name and get the representation as you worked in the console. ...

Comment: <continued> That was a big improvement over Python for interactive work. Then the leap with IPython lead to IPython Notebook where you could better document along with IPython use. Then IPython Notebook evolved into the Jupyter project by allowing other kernels. So a lot of the Jupyter stuff you work with in the Python-based kernels nherits from IPython and builds on that. It's also help to keep in mind the REPL model (Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop) in this context.