# python/sage: how to get the last expression?

Tags: python, jupyter, sage

If I do in Jupiter (in both python and sage) something like:

```
a = 42
b = 43
a + b
```

it will, somehow, manage to understand that this process returns the value `a + b`, i.e. 85 here:

[image]

Similarly, if I just do:

```
a = 42
```

it will understand that there is nothing to return.

I would like now to do something similar for a different application (to cache the result of a python operation)… how could I get this information, ideally by just running the code and appending some python code to obtain this information? I tried to do:

```py
a = 42
b = 43
a + b
print(_)
```

but this fails. I was thinking to do something stupid like adding `res =`  in front of the last line, but it might fail for instance if the last line is indented etc… How can I elegantly obtain this information?

Comment: which "information" you want to obtain? results of a+b... assigning it?! c = a+b

Comment: I follow what you are saying up until the paragraph that begins `I would like now to do something similar for a different application`. A few questions I am unclear on -- a) Will this be in Jupyter? You only mention Python. b) Is that last code block meant to be in a Jupyter Cell? Separate lines in a Pyton Console? c) You write, "How can I elegantly obtain this information?" What information from the last section should it get? Your title says, 'how to get the last variable', which would be `b`. Should your title say the 'last expression'?

Comment: "to cache the result of a python operation" - Are you looking for Python Shelve module? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78042609/8508004).

Comment: The REPL's parser knows when it has parsed an expression statement (a statement consisting of a single expression), and the REPL can make use of that to capture the value and print it, as well as assigning that value to `_` implicitly. This isn't something in the Python data model itself, which is why your attempt failed if you were executing code *noninteractively* from a script.

Comment: @Milan basically, I want to emulate the `_` of python REPL (to print the result in a file) in plain python script. How is Jupiter doing that?

Comment: @Wayne : the application is for robust-externalize, a library to cache code, including python code, in LaTeX. When I type `\cacheMe{some python code}`, I want to compute the last expression, and save the result in a file (possibly doing different operations on its type, e.g. an image etc). So I need to know what to write in the source, and how to compile it (ideally just `python myfile`), so that it saves the output to some other files.

Comment: @chepner so how can I adapt this to a non-interactive use-case? I guess it must somehow be possible since Jupiter is doing exactly that, and in a more robust way that with `_`.

Comment: Jupiter implements its own REPL, just like CPython does.

Comment: @chepner so jupiter needs to have a python parser??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was already asked as part of [a post entitled 'Get value and type of python variable similar to Jupyter behavior'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75654750/8508004) where the OP had already made significant progress towards getting to the solution.

The resulting approach is to use Python `exec()` to first run the code in the lines and then use Python `eval()` to evaluate the last expression, like Jupyter does with the default setting for [`InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75186119/8508004).

I'll refine* & transpose [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75655825/8508004) from there for the specific code situation here:

```py
lines = """a = 42
b = 43
a + b"""

exec(lines,globals(),locals())
print(eval(lines.split("\n")[-1]))
```

That prints the result of `85` as expected.

The OP points out a concern about indentation. Indeed, I do note that my present proposed solution will fail though if the last line is indented. This could be addressed, I believe. If the last line has any degree of indentation I can collect the lines prior back until the level of indenting is the outer level. Then use those collected lines as 'the last expression' and evaluate it. I haven't done that here though because the solution without implementing that part is fairly clear and I didn't want to make it more abstruse with the addition of that yet.

**Make sure to read the warning about `exec()` and `eval()` over [where I had originally posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75655825/8508004) this approach.**

In response to a comment, I'll also highlight in the answer you can further make things more feature rich or combine in other ways to bring the Jupyter/IPython abilities into Python because you can do imports. [At my answer in the thread 'How do I construct a python function where the input in python code and output is ipython rich output (in HTML)?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694087/8508004), I have the section 'UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO FIRST COMMENT:' where I talk about **using IPython as an import in Python** to capture RichOutput, with that approach further [fleshed out in a demo](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/405e049fa082cca9b7a0ef0bee904b4f) that goes into some acrobatics you can do utilizing methods and functions from IPython in Jupyter.

*(I did end up refining my old answer at the other place prompted by transposing it to here. Revisiting the answer I had there uncovered an issue were I wasn't splitting right to get the actual last line for evaluating. I just got lucky last time that the last line in my original answer was one character & so the last line and last character were the same in the original case. I now fixed it there, too.)

Comment: Thanks! Note that the answer you link contains an interesting code that uses IPython as a library to execute the code.

Comment: "Note that the answer you link contains an interesting code that uses IPython as a library to execute the code." I think you are referring to if one follows a link about the warning, one ends up in [at my answer in the thread 'How do I construct a python function where the input in python code and output is ipython rich output (in HTML)?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694087/8508004), I have the section 'UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO FIRST COMMENT:' where I talk about using IPython as an import in Python to capture RichOutput, with this ...

Comment: <continued> [fleshed out demo](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/405e049fa082cca9b7a0ef0bee904b4f)? Yes, that is there but you kept insisting you couldn't use IPython and only pure Python. However, maybe you didn't know you can import IPython, too, and you should be able to perhaps use that where you are working? As it may be helpful to others then, I can highlight it in my answer, too. Especially in light of IPython supporting more of what you originally described out-of-the-box and so others may end up here who can use IPython as an import in Python.

Comment: Yeah, I do prefer pure python as my users might not have ipython installed, but I was also unaware of the fact that ipython can be imported as a library. Do you know if this can also be applied to sage?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you mean specifically by Sage? I have used SageMath Online in the past; however, it was a while ago and I'm not sure at this time of the abilities in it vs. standard Jupyter.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sage has an executable `sage foo.sage` that runs the code in foo.sage, not sure if we can do a sinilar trick.

Comment: I see some of that [here](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/operators.html). The main page of reference seems to be [here](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/reference/). It looks a lot like [here](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/reference/cpython/sage/cpython/atexit.html), it can import a lot of Python stuff.

Comment: I see some of that [here](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/operators.html). The main page of reference seems to be [here](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/reference/). It looks like based on [here](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/reference/cpython/sage/cpython/atexit.html), it can import a lot of Python stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ipython`, there are various ways of referencing a previous `out` line:

```
In [113]: a = 42
     ...: b = 43
     ...: a + b
Out[113]: 85

In [114]: _     # also __ and ___
Out[114]: 85

In [115]: _113
Out[115]: 85

In [116]: Out[113]
Out[116]: 85
```

`Out` is a list of values

There isn't a way of referencing an unassigned line in a cell, as you want:

```
a = 42
b = 43
a + b
print(?)
```

Using `a+b;` will also surpress the last display/save, same as doing `c = a+b`.

`_` also works in a plain interactive python session.   jupyter/ipython enhances that history collection.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use ipython, I basically need to do it in plain python. Basically, I'd like to understand how jupyter can do that. Also, the `_` is not resiliant to stuff like `_ = 42`, while jupyter manages to get that one right.

Comment: I thought you were asking about using jupyter/ipython, which has it's oen enhanced interactive REPL..It's no clear from your comments whether you are using plain python in script mode, interactive mode, or trying to develop your own REPL.

Comment: I'm using plain python.

Comment: All this is part of the REPL, a program that accepts blocks of text (possibly even provides editing ability), executes it in a python session (with global namespace, etc), and receives back a result, which it then displays (if not None).  With a script you need to save the values to variables.  You can also use python's own `pickle` and `shelf` to save variables to files.

Comment: and how is the "execute and receives back a result" done? Do they use some python API of a VM etc?